# Waypoints js not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-waypoints

I am working on a website with one-page scroll layout. I am using the jquery.onepage-scroll.js library for the layout. And i want to add animations while the different sections are scrolled. I tried using the waypoints library to achieve the same but the problem is that the events are not firing when i scroll the page, rather when i click "Inspect element" in the Chrome, only then the event associated with waypoints(in my case, the event is alert message) gets fired. I am not able to figure out the exact problem here.

Here is how my webpage is structured:

```
<div class="main">
<section id="page1"></section>
<section id="page2"></section>
<section id="page3"></section>
</div>
```

And here is how i have associated an alert to the waypoint function just to check if it works:

```
$("section#page2").waypoint(function(){
            alert('waypoint ok');
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are conflicts between Waypoint and jquery.onepage-scroll.js Plugin. If I were you I would switch to a plugin that has more option, I've used [FullPage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js)

there are way more options and you can do anything you want like [**this**](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/apple.html) where you can add custom animations.

you can use `afterSlideLoad` to do whatever you want once you slide to a cetain page

```
afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){

        //first slide of the second section
        if(anchorLink == 'secondPage' && slideIndex == 1){
            alert("First slide loaded");
        }

        //second slide of the second section (supposing #secondSlide is the
        //anchor for the second slide
        if(index == 2 && slideIndex == 'secondSlide'){
            alert("Second slide loaded");
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. You answer really helped me figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <h1 class="animated" data-animation="fadeInDown" data-revert="fadeOutDown">Some Animation Here</h1>
```

You can get animation while he tag visible in window. You can check animation effect in animate.css.

here is [jsfiffle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6LKKe/)